# How to show a relation is/isn't reflexive, transitive, or symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I was tasked with this:

> Define a relation on **Z** by setting *x R y* if *xy* is even.
>
> (a) Give a counterexample to show that *R* is not reflexive.

How do I go about proving this? Do I express this in terms of predicate logic or something and use laws and rules and the like to prove this? I think I have an idea of what I need to do, though I don't think I have a correct understanding.

I would start by saying assume xy is odd. Then, by definition of odd, xy = 2k + 1, where k is any integer. From here on, I'm stuck. I know reflexivity involves something like *x R x* but I don't know how to apply that to this problem.

Any help is appreciated, especially before 8am Eastern 2/18/15 when this homework is due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that $R$ is reflexive means:

> for every $x\in\Bbb Z$ we have $x\,R\,x$.

To show that $R$ is not reflexive, you need to give one example where the statement $x\,R\,x$ is false.

In this case "$x\,R\,y$'' means "$xy$ is even", so "$x\,R\,x$" means "$x^2$ is even".  Can you find an example of an integer $x$ such that $x^2$ is not even?

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me understand more than just that question!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!